# ParentFragment is null

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a question , I don't understand why my parentFragment is null.
I have a `FragmentA` who call a `FragmentB` (BottomSheet).

```java
FragmentBBottomSheet.newInstance().show(
    childFragmentManager,
    TAG_FRAGMENT_B,
)
```

in my `FragmentB`, I try to call a `method` from `FragmentA` like

```java
(parentFragment as FragmentA).methodOfFragmentA.
```

my `parentFragment is null`, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I did it like this

**Parent Fragment**

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,container,false)
        val btn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            val frag = ChildFragment()
            frag.show(childFragmentManager,"")
        }
        return view
    }
    fun showToast(){
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Called from child frag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

**Child/BottomSheet Fragment**

```
class ChildFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        (parentFragment as FragmentA).showToast()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank2, container, false)
    }
}
```

There was no NPE when calling the parents fragment's method